# barplot with bars hanging from the top

Tags: r, graph, plot

i have a mock example:

```
a<-seq(1:5)
barplot(a)
```

Now I wish to have the bars hanging off from axis 3 (the top one) and not going up from axis 1 (The normal x axis one sees in any plot(a) function. (This could be done for any other plot, too, I suppose).

The idea is to have precipitation data hanging off the top of my plot with a y axis on the right of my graph.

How do I go about?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: can we do this in `ggplot2` yet?

Comment: @Tobias, if an answer works for you, be sure to accept and/or up-vote it.

Answer (score 4):

Use `barplot(a, ylim = rev(range(c(0, a))))` to make your chart go from top to bottom.

You can use `yaxt = "n"` and `axis()` to plot your axis on the right.

```
barplot(a, ylim = rev(range(a)), yaxt = "n")
axis(4, at = a)
```

This is the output of that previous example:

[image]